# RxJS: How to wrap and observe string for changes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, primitive-types

RxJS: How do you wrap a primitive type such as a *string* in an *Observable* and **listen to changes to that primitive**?

Consider the following example. `setTimeout` simulates some external event that changes the string `s`. However, the `console.log` only fires once and not after `setTimeout` is called. Why is that?

```
let s = "Hello World";
Observable.of(s).subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
});
// some external event changes variable s
setTimeout( () => {
    s = "Wat?";
}, 1000);
// Output: prints "Hello World" to console, but not "Wat?"
```

This question might sound a bit dumb, but I searched for 2 hours through all kinds of RxJS docs and examples and most of them play with Arrays or Objects. This is not what I want. I don't want to change attributes, functions, arrays or anything like that. Just a plain string or boolean or number.

Comment: Strings are immutable though.

Comment: Valid point. So RxJS doesn't take that into account?

Comment: Well in your sample code, there's the primitive string *value* `"Hello World"`, and then there's the *variable* `s`.  It seems like you want to have the variable be the thing you observe, and not so much the string value (which is good because the string value is not going to change).

Comment: That's right. I meant the variable s, not the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are thinking about streams incorrectly. The whole point of the stream is that you should *not* be mutating objects directly (strings can't actually be mutated as @Pointy already mentioned but this is a more general point).

You need to shift your thinking to seeing data as immutable and the stream as representing the change which your react to in the subscriber.

In your example, if you wanted to "mutate" a string, what you are really trying to do is capture a set of changes and surface them through the `next` handler of the `subscribe` method. Where those changes come from is irrelevant from the string's perspective, it only cares that events are being passed through it.

i.e. I could do the following to emit different strings:

```
Rx.Observable.timer(1000)
  .mapTo('Wat')
  .startWith('Hello World!')
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

What you need to determine is what the source of your changes is and what events it should emit. From there Rx can help you massage that data into something that you can use downstream.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to be clear: RxJS doesn't have anything to do with the deprecated vanilla JS `Object.observe()` method and nothing with, say, observables in Knockout or Angular 2?! I guess I thought of RxJS as a replacement for these more traditional observers. After all, RxJS called itself the *Lodash for Observables*, although they removed that from the website apparently.

Answer (score 6):

I do realize that this question has an accepted answer but here is the proper way to observer a string for changes using RxJS.

Create a variable for type [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md)

```
stringVariable$: ReplaySubject<String> = new ReplaySubject<String>();
```

Assign all new values to `stringVariable` via a function to catch the update event.

```
assignNewValue(newValue: String) {
    this.stringVariable$.next(newValue);
}
```

Subscribe to this Observable

```
stringVariable$.subscribe((newValue: String) => {
    console.log(newValue);
});
```

Alternatively you can use a [BehaviourSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) if your string variable has a initial value to start with.

Comment: Your `this.stringVariable$` has to be a member variable ? Could it be a local variable and passed in as an argument to a method that would do the `subjectParam$.next()` call ?

Comment: it need not be a member variable.